# PHP proper way to redirect to different folder

Tags: php, redirect

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
/index.php

/my-app
   index.php
```

The root index.php has the following script and I want it to redirect to the my-app folder.

```
header('Location: my-app/');
```

Is this the proper way to redirect if the base path is not set, ie http://example.org/? Or should I use `/my-app/` instead?

Comment: I'd do `header('Location: ./my-app'); die();`.. could try with or without the trailing slash..

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: the full url is "proper"

Answer (score 0):

Trying giving full to the url to the header or you can use the alternate method:

```
header('Location: ../my-app/');
```

In the above double dots take you one level up from current directory.Hence you can try to the level of directory and search.